# How to let another image animate

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I was adding something to my XNA project, and I downloaded the GIF animation library from https://xnagif.codeplex.com/

I added the pipeline and references as needed (I followed the sample GIF animation) and one of my gif images worked (yay) but I have decided to add more gif images and only the first image loaded animates normally, while the other ones do not...I just see a still image/frame.

How am I supposed to fix that?

Also just something extra, how can I make it so that I do not have specific color in the spritebatch.Draw parameters? I want the colors to remain as they are from image, but I can't find a way to get rid of the color restriction to be incolved as a parameter also. How can I get rid of that?

Comment: The last paragraph of this should be a separate question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After long thought, I figured out a while ago that I had to update time in the other functions in seemed.